# Custom plugin not logging

Tags: java, xmpp, tigase

I've made a custom component, and I'm currently trying to check the logs at logs/tigase.log.0 to check if it's working. However, I can't find any of the plugin's logs, even though I see it as active using PSI (as well as the tigase-console.log)

I've enabled the debugging in the properties:

```
--debug=server,xmpp.impl,xmpp.XMPPIOService
--debug-packages=customplugin.tigase
--sm-plugins=+jabber:iq:register,+jabber:iq:auth,+urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl,+urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind,+urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session,+roster-presence,+jabber:iq:privacy,+jabber:iq:version,+http://jabber.org/protocol/stats,+starttls,+msgoffline,+vcard-temp,+http://jabber.org/protocol/commands,+jabber:iq:private,+urn:xmpp:ping,+basic-filter,+domain-filter,-message,-message-all,+message-carbons,+amp,+customplugin
```

For testing, inside the plugin I've tried the following:

```
log.log(Level.FINEST, "ryuu:ryuu");
log.log(Level.ALL, "ryuu:ryuu");
log.log(Level.INFO, "ryuu:ryuu");
log.log(Level.SEVERE, "ryuu:ryuu");
```

But when I try to tail tigase's logs (which the plugin should output to):

```
tail -f logs/tigase.log.0 | grep "ryuu:ryuu"
```

I don't get anything at all, even though I can see the plugin is active using PSI's commands. What might be the reason for that?

Comment: Did you check the program has write permission in the folder where the log file will go? Maybe it can't create the log file

Comment: Tigase is able to log to the file, as I'm seeing the logs of the other components and plugins in the log file.

Comment: @Pat Are you using eclipse in debug mode ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I had the ELEM_NAME wrong. 
I had set it to be the same as the plugin ID, but it needs to be the same as the element it's handling. In this case, "message".